# How do you calculate out-of-sample error in case of numeric response variable?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to predict the "medv" (median owner-owned house prices) from Boston dataset. It is a numeric variable.

I have made a linear model from a training dataset and want to calculate model accuracy by testing on a test dataset. Below is the reproducible code:

```
library("MASS")
Boston<-Boston

set.seed(12396911) # set random seed
index <- sample(1:nrow(Boston), floor(0.8 * nrow(Boston)), replace = FALSE)
training <- Boston[index,]
testing<- Boston[-index,]

fin_model<-lm(medv ~ lstat + rm + ptratio + black + dis + nox + zn + chas + rad + tax + crim, data = training)
prediction<-predict(fin_model,testing)


tab<-data.frame(cbind(prediction,testing$medv))
colnames(tab)<-c("pred","true")
mse<-sum((tab$pred - tab$true)^2)/(length(tab)-1)
mse
```

I have an idea on how to calculate accuracy when we are predicting a categorical response (it comparing the true value against predicted and hence it's either yes or no, and the proportion of matches is our accuracy).

I was thinking if `correlation` makes sense as a measure of accuracy: If 1 it's 100% accurate and if it's 0, predictions are useless. But I am not sure.

```
cor(tab$pred,tab$true)
# 0.8522107
```

Comment: How best to assess the accuracy/quality of a statistical model is quite a broad question. A good starting point would be a textbook (for example Hastie & Tibshirani & Friedman's [The Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf)); In your case, I would start with e.g. calculating the RMSE  `rmse <- sqrt(mean((prediction - testing$medv)^2))` and use that for comparing models. Or you can look into information theoretic criteria such as BIC, AIC, ...

Comment: Thanks Maurits for the reply. Indeed, I wanted to compare a bunch of models from different subsets based on AIC, BIC  but also on model accuracy, so that I can give a complete picture. I wanted to show something like: this model is the best model because it has got better AIC, BIC, R-adjusted values and also it has got a good accuracy when deployed on testing dataset. I have got the AIC, BIC values, I am just thinking about how to calculate the accuracy.

Comment: Just to be clear: There is no such thing as calculating THE accuracy. You can assess the accuracy/quality of a statistical model using various metrics. RSME is one measure for the model's accuracy; R^2, which is closely related to the Pearson's correlation coefficient, is another; the `glm` function returns the model's deviance to assess the quality of the fit.

Comment: One more thing: You say that *"correlation makes sense as a measure of accuracy"*. Indeed it does, and this is in essence what you use when looking at R^2 values. See the [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Available in the `caret` package, `postResample(prediction, actual)` where prediction and actual are both numeric or factor vectors will give you RMSE, Rsquared, and MAE